# Adding a transform function to Meteor.users?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

Some of my collections are declared like this

```
export default Foos = new Meteor.Collection('foo', {
  transform(foo) {
    foo.someMethod = someMethod;

    return foo;
  }
});
```

How do I apply a transformation function to the `Meteor.users` collection?

---

### Update

My hack, currently, is to manually set it.

```
Meteor.users._transform = function (user) { ... return user; }
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already figured out how to add the `transform` function, but there is one more thing you should do. That is to wrap your function with `LocalCollection.wrapTransform` prior to assigning it to `_transform`:

```
Meteor.users._transform = LocalCollection.wrapTransform(function(user) { ... });
```

Doing this will make sure the returned objects contain the `_id` field so that [subsystems can keep track of the objects identities](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/87681c8f166641c6c3e34958032a5a070aa2d11a/packages/minimongo/wrap_transform.js#L1-L4). Also you need to add `minimongo` to your project to use this wrap function.

Comment: Yup, `minimongo@1.0.19` already installed. Thanks for the suggestion!